# Broken chart images in Crystal Reports in web application

Tags: web-applications, crystal-reports

I have a collection of crystal reports that contains charts.  They look fine locally and when printed, but when viewing them through a web application using a `CrystalReportViewer` the charts dispay as broken images.

Viewing the properties of the broken image show the url as `...CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_8d12a01f-b336-4b8b-b0c7-83d9571d87e4.png`.

I have tried adding

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" 
        type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler,CrystalDecisions.Web,
        Version=Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral,
        PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

to the `web.config` as suggested via a google search but that has not resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a permissions issue on the Crystal libraries?? I've run into that before with Crystal, not specfically the ImageHandler though.